# table-header-group , table-footer-group properties doesn't work in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, header, pagination, footer

This is my code. http://furkan.brove.net/syflm.php

It is not working in Chrome when i print it. I wish it puts header and footer on every page in print mode. Also in every browser last footer is going bottom of the content. But i want it to be bottom of the page.

Is there any way to solve my problem?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-9">
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
<meta name="googlebot" content="noindex">
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">    
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />

<title>Brove.NET ISO Yazılımı</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/pagination.css" />
<style>
    #all thead { display: table-header-group; }
    #all tfoot { display: table-footer-group; }
    .header_table{ height:100px; }
    .footer_table{ height:100px; }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<table id="all">
   <thead><tr><td><table class="header_table"><tr><td>Your header goes here</td></tr></table></td></tr></thead>
   <tfoot><tr><td><table class="footer_table"><tr><td>Your footer goes here</td></tr></table></td></tr></tfoot>
   <tbody>
     <tr><td>
       Page body in here -- as long as it needs to be<br />
       <!-- i wrote this many -->
     </td></tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

This is IE screenshot. In second page it puts header and footer well.

[image]

This is Firefox screenshot. It is working too.

[image]

But in chrome it is not working

[image]

Comment: Could you give a link to where it is to test? Or perhaps a screenshot?

Comment: I edited the code im prepearing screetshot now

Comment: Aren't those display values the defaults for `thead` and `tfoot` anyway? You shouldn't need to set them at all.

Comment: i edited the code. i didnt understand you exactly

Answer (score 6):

This is a known issue with Webkit, unfortunately.

Here it is on the Chrome issue tracker: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=24826

And the Webkit issue tracker: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=17205

Star it on the Chrome issue tracker if you want to show that it is important to you (I did).

Comment: I figured this answer was out of date. Then I checked the links. I wish I was wrong...