# table-header-group not working in chrome

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, tableheader

Although the following code doesn't work in chrome as said in the answer of [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8984032/table-header-group-table-footer-group-properties-doesnt-work-in-chrome),

```
<style type="text/css">
    @media print
    {
      thead { display:table-header-group }
      tbody { display:table-row-group }
      tfoot { display:table-footer-group }
    }
</style>
```

Is there any other tricks/hacks using jquery or so to fix the same in chrome?

My sample table is here: http://jsfiddle.net/mpsbhat/b6cxmqyj/2/

Comment: [Chromium bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=24826). [Webkit bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=34218)

Comment: Any hacks using jquery @dcc?

Comment: How is the Pentaho reporter and other reporting tools working then?

Comment: Just do it without using those elements.  There are always half a dozen different ways to do just about everything.  I'm not clear on what exactly your intention is so can't provide any further detail.

Comment: I just wanted to know how the repeating header works like a charm in pentaho like reporting tools irrespective of browsers. How they handled this issue that I asked as my question.