# I need to repeat the table heading on every printable page with jquery datatable on chrome browser?

Tags: jquery, html, printing, datatable, datatables

In my page.blade.php I have a jQuery Datatable. Now I need to repeating table head every pages when I print the report. I've tried by using this

```
@media print { thead {display: table-header-group;} }
```

But I can't. Please tell me how can I add this in my project on every printable datatable reports? Now this table header showing on only top page (page one) when I print it, it doesn't showing other pages!!

Comment: Can you put up a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) of your jquery and relevant css with maybe some dummy data?

Comment: yap. http://jsfiddle.net/v000as21/ Please run it on chorme browser!

Comment: So is it working in your jsfiddle and not in your actual version?

Comment: No not working on jsfiddle! Again; I need to repeat the table heading on every printable page on chrome browser. but it doesn't showing!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [table-header-group , table-footer-group properties doesn't work in Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8984032/table-header-group-table-footer-group-properties-doesnt-work-in-chrome)

Comment: A work around i use by using Tabletools plugin, export the table in PDF, and there i got the table heading in every printable page....

Comment: @InspireShahin your jsfiddle example is working for me. Please test the real printer or PDF.